# Error in commands involving pip in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pip

Using the command `pip --version` gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/johns/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/johns/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
```

I'm new to Ubuntu & I also tried the following commands which also gives me the same error

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip --version
```

Comment: Try ``python3 -m pip --version``

Comment: As I have mentioned I have already tried                                                              python3 -m pip --version. But still not working